# bulk host to Ip procedure on windows 10 as I am a beginner - script way

Tags: java, linux, windows, unix, scripting

Experts,

can anybody pls let me know how can I convert bunch of hosts to respective ip addresses. I have all host details in notepad and need Ips for same . If possible pls let me know if host and ips both can be captured to avoid what ip is for what host issue, better to have them in excel in 12 columns, appreciate your response.

Regards,
Pasha

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the "nslookup" command takes a DNS name and returns its IP address.  In Linux, the "host" command does the same thing.  Is that what you're asking?